# Terminating app due to uncaught exception, while loading a view

Tags: iphone, ios

I am getting this error, while I am trying to load another view

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '- 
>   [__NSCFType new1:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x5c27950'

Here new1 is a button, which when pressed loads a view.

And here is the code inside the new1

```
-(IBAction) new1:(id) sender
{
 viewController = [[iTViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"iTViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
    [self.view addSubview:viewController.view];
}
```

**Note: When I launch the App from fresh and press the new1 button, it works flawlessly, but when I press other button which loads other view and when I return back to this view and press new1, then it crashes**

Answer (score 1):

The error `* Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '- [__NSCFType new1:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x5c27950'` may not be coming from inside the `- (IBAction)new1:(id)sender` method.  What that error is saying is that you are trying to call a non-existent method on whatever object is at the address `0x5c27950`.  Here are a few possible solutions:

Set NSZombieEnabled, malloc stack logging, and guard malloc in the debugger.  Then, when your App crashes, type this in the gdb comsole:

```
(gdb) info malloc-history 0x5c27950
```

Replace 0x5c27950 with the address of the object that the stack trace says caused the crash,and it will give you a much more useful stack trace and it should highlight the exact line that is causing the problem.

[Check out this article for more info on NSZombieEnabled](http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?NSZombieEnabled).

[This one for MallocStackLogging info](http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?MallocStackLogging)

[More info on guard malloc here](http://www.duffresearch.com/blog/exc_bad_access-guard-malloc-and-you)

---

Also, have you tried pushing the view controller (assuming your using a navigation controller):

```
- (IBAction)new1:(id)sender {
    iTViewController *viewController = [[iTViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"iTViewController" bundle:nil];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:viewController animated:YES];
    [viewController release];
}
```

Or, if you are not using a nav controller, you can present it modally:

```
- (IBAction)new1:(id)sender {
    iTViewController *viewController = [[iTViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"iTViewController" bundle:nil];
    [self presentModalViewController:viewController animated:YES];
    [viewController release];
}
```

---

Another possibility is that you are calling `[self new1:someButton];` but the method is not declared in your header file like so:

```
@interface MyViewController: UIViewController {
    ........
}

- (IBAction)new1:(id)sender;

@end
```

Comment: Pushing viewcontroler shows error and I am not using nav controller. And I have declared the method in header. Will try the NSZombieEnabled method and will update here